# Storing constants in Java

Tags: java

I have a table of chars and for each char an int value is affected. (I will use this table to calculate a barcode check digit).

I want to store this table as constants, what is the best way to do it in java please? (Enum, Hashmap...)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need this table to be constant or the contents to be constant?

Comment: You can use public static final variables

Comment: Depends a bit on how you intend to use it, if you want to look up the int value by char, use a `Map`, if you want to refer to constants by name, use an `Enum`.

Comment: @ci_ yes the int value is will be retrived using the char value so it's a Map many thanks :)

Comment: For objcts, there is no real synonmy to C/C++'s `const` keyword. You can make an object (e.g. a `Map`) `final`, but you can still change its content.

Comment: difference between EnumMap and HashMap is performance, due to specialized optimization done for Enum keys, EnumMap is likely to perform better than HashMap when using enum as key object. check the difference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mapping between letters and codes is as in your own answer, then you do not need a table. You can do this with a simple translation method:

```
public static int letterToCode(char letter) {
    if (letter >= '0' && letter <= '9') {
        return letter - '0';
    } else if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
        return letter - 'A' + 10;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid letter: " + letter);
    }
}

public static char codeToLetter(int code) {
    if (code >= 0 && code <= 9) {
        return (char) ('0' + code);
    } else if (code >= 10 && code <= 35) {
        return (char) ('A' + code - 10);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid code: " + code);
    }
}
```

This will not perform worse than looking up the code or letter in a map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `public static final DATA_TYPE VAR_NAME;` for it to work. Final causes the variable to not be manipulated but you need static in front of it because if you don't it will give you and error.